# Do a dependency analysis of tests using Sonar (or other)

Tags: java, testing, dependencies, maven, sonarqube

I have a multi module maven project. I set up Sonar. The most interesting part for me right now is the dependency analysis on package level including the (JUnit) tests.

Unfortunatly Sonar seems to ignore the tests at least for the dependency analysis. Is there a way to change that?

If this is not possible, is there a way to get the dependency matrix for my tests (or tests + main src) using another free tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JDepend](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jdepend-maven-plugin/) maybe?

BTW, I'm curious why do you need dependency analysis on tests? Maybe [a code coverage report](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage) is what you're looking for instead?

Comment: I does analyze dependencies, but it doesn't produce the matrix or something comparable ... so there would be quite some work involved to get it to a useful state.